# How to make action button refreshing the plot?

Tags: r, shiny

I want the plot to refresh only after: changing the sliders and pressing the actionbutton. I don't want the plot to refhres after changing radioButton. How can I do this? I tried this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#data change only once at the begenin
dt <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider1","slider1", value=5, min=1, max=10),
  sliderInput("slider2","slider2", value=0.8, min=0, max=1),
  radioButtons("check1","check1",choices = c("red","blue","green")),
  actionButton("refreshColours","refreshColours"),
  plotOutput("rys")
)


server <- function(input,output){

  pp <- reactive({
    ggplot(dt, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point(size=input$slider1, alpha=input$slider2, colour=isolate(input$check1))
  })

  pp <- eventReactive(input$refreshColours{pp})

  output$rys <- renderPlot({
    pp()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

but I don't know how to refresh plot after pressing the action button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#data change only once at the begenin
dt <- data.frame(x=runif(1000), y=runif(1000))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider1","slider1", value=5, min=1, max=10),
  sliderInput("slider2","slider2", value=0.8, min=0, max=1),
  radioButtons("check1","check1",choices = c("red","blue","green")),
  actionButton("refreshColours","refreshColours"),
  plotOutput("rys")
)


server <- function(input,output){
  pp <- eventReactive(c(input$refreshColours,input$slider2,input$slider1),{
    ggplot(dt, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point(size=input$slider1, alpha=input$slider2, colour=isolate(input$check1))
  })
  output$rys <- renderPlot({
    pp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: no, cuz I want to refresh the plot after clicking the action button AND CHANGING THE SLIDER and in your solution the plot will refresh only after clicking the action button.

Comment: that I was afraid of. Thx. And why this approach doesn't work? server <- function(input,output){
  
  col1 <- eventReactive(input$refreshColour,{input$check1})
  
  pp <- reactive({

    ggplot(dt, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point(size=input$slider1, alpha=input$slider2, colour=col1())
  })
  output$rys <- renderPlot({
    pp()
  })
  
}

Comment: Your button name is `input$refreshColours` and not `input$refreshColour`. Please try to use different names for Title and the actual `div` name

Comment: Thank you. I wish ya will go to the Heaven. :)